# Is there anything in TypeScript similar to Class<T> in Java, to extract the type of a class constructor?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I need such a feature like Class in Java for TypeScript, but I haven't been able to find it.

`Class<T>` is what I'm looking for.
I think it could be `NewableFunction<T>`. But there is no such thing.
I can't use `Map<A, InstanceType<A>>`, obviously it's not correct.

The "setIt" method and "the left end of this Map" to passing only the type of class A and subclasses of class A, not its instances or a class that are not subclasses of A.

I know that Typescript compiles to Javascript with type erasure just like Java does.

```js
class Foo {
  public static readonly bar : Map<Class<A>, A>;

  public static declare getIt(clazz: Class<A>) : A;

  public static setIt(clazz: Class<A>) : A {
    const a = new clazz();
    this.bar.set(clazz, a);
    return a;
  }
}

declare class A;
declare class B extends A;
```

The left side of the dictionary is its class, and the right side is the object of the corresponding class.

---

And the declaration of covariant and contravariant classes?
Such as "in" and "out" key words of kotlin.
I'm looking for that too.

```kotlin
class Foo{
  public map: Map<Class<in A>, A>
  public setIt(clazz: Class<in A>): A;
}
```

I searched for it and also looked at the official documentation, including the type declaration for stdlib. But I didn't get any results.

Comment: 2. One question per question would be more appropriate.

Comment: @Touffy I want to ask a question about "Class<T>", not "<T>", It represents a type, which is something like a constructor. I tried to edit the problem again, but StackOverflow kept telling me it was formatted incorrectly and couldn't be edited. I'm sure it's only two parts of the code, and it's already in three quotes.

Comment: I get that (after carefully reading your examples). But initially, I assumed that you wrote "Class" as a placeholder for any class name.

Comment: If I understand your use case correctly, I would suggest "Can I extract the type of a class constructor in TypeScript ?".

Comment: If you still can't edit, would you mind if I improved the first part (again, assuming I understood what you actually want) and removed the second part ?

Comment: I looked up Wikipedia about what is RTFM, I'm sorry about it. I have poor English, and the translation function of my browser is broken, so I used OCR's translation to read your answer bit by bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About your first question, yes. If you define a class with

```
class A {}
```

then you have two things : the actual `A`, which is a constructor (a kind of function), and the type `A`, which types *instances of A*.

But you can get the type of the constructor (the actual thing stored in `A`) with **`typeof A`**.

In you example, translating to TypeScript, you'd get :

```
const foo = {
  bar : new Map<typeof A, A>(),

  getIt(clazz: typeof A) : A | undefined {
    return this.bar.get(clazz)
  },

  setIt(clazz: typeof A) : A {
    const a = new clazz()
    this.bar.set(clazz, a)
    return a
  }
}
```

I translated your class Foo to a basic object because it had only static properties, which in TypeScript makes no sense as a class.

Comment: Thanks, I intended to restrict the "setIt" method and "the left end of this Map" to passing only the type of class A and subclasses of class A, not its instances or a class that are not subclasses of A. I'm not asking this question for its constructor. "setIt" returns an instance of the subclass of A corresponding to the passed argument. (I'll use extra instanceof if possible.)

Comment: In JavaScript, a "class" *is* a constructor, and the type of a class is… nothing. You can't store a "type" in a Map. You can manipulate types with TypeScript, sure, but ultimately, the actual thing in JavaScript will be a constructor or an instance of it. What TypeScript can do for you is help you type your Map. But I think I have a better idea for your example.

Comment: I see, maybe I should use a string key instead of this way of using a type.

Comment: Nah, you can do it with constructors. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you. That solves my problem. I think it's complicated. Covariant and contravariant is also part of this question, but Typescript seems to be far less complex, making this second question less relevant.